# Beach North Italy

Tags: italy, road-trips, beaches

I am doing a road trip next summer and will be near Genoa in Italy. I am wondering does anyone have the name of some smaller towns/hotels on the sea around there?

I searched TripAdvisor's Best Beach Section but most where in South Italy or Sicily.

Comment: Sorry but Stack Exchange doesn't allow questions that would be better on a regular forum because they don't have "right answers". You're asking for a whole list of beaches, for recommendations, or for a poll. But none of these things are allowed because Stack Exchange is not a forum but a place to store correct answers to questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from Savona, about 50km west of Genoa, and which has a couple of nice beaches, you have Garbasso, Celle Ligure, Varazze, San Giacomo, Cogoleto, Arenzano and Terrarossa.

And going east you have Sori, Recco and Camogli - smaller villages which may be more what you want.

You can easily check them out on Google maps with Streetview to see what you would prefer.

Comment: Cheers. I was going to use Streetview just needed somewhere to start.

Comment: Personally I'd go east if you like small, countryside roads and a bit of open land. Heading westwards you get more urban development.

Comment: East it is as we will already have visited Brussels, Berlin, Munich and Zurich on the trip and might need some time to relax.

Comment: If you want to go east you should also consider the 5 terre: they are only 90 km from Genova.

Answer (score 0):

Forte dei Marmi is a sea town and comune in the province of Lucca, in northern Tuscany (Italy) located approximately 110 kms South of Genoa. It is the birthplace of Paola Ruffo di Calabria, Queen of the Belgians from 1993 to 2013.

[image]

Tourism is the principal activity of Forte dei Marmi's citizens. The population of the town, amounting to some 7,700, nearly triples during the summer, because of the hundreds of tourist who mainly come from Florence, Milan, Germany, and Russia.

Obviously if you are driving from Genoa you can admire the towns, villages and coast line along the way. But Forte dei Marmi is a must see destination, just to see the *bling* and pretend you are part of the jet-set (even if you are not !).

More info:

[Official Website](http://www.comune.fortedeimarmi.lu.it/it/home.html)

[Telegraph (UK) Travel Review](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/ultratravel/7973275/Victorias-Secrets-Forte-dei-Marmi-Italy.html)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forte_dei_Marmi